# Are there other options for reducing glare on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro

I'm discouraged that for those of us wanting matte displays, we have to get a pretty crummy looking white-gray border around the screen rather than the sleek black edge that normal MacBook Pros come with:

[image]

Is there a way to get a matte display without having to get the terrible-looking edge? Could I buy a regular MacBook and use some commercial screen overlay which would give the same effect without compromising the black edge?

Comment: Uh, there is no "normal" MacBook Pro. MacBook Pros and PowerBooks had matte screens long before Apple went to glossy. I have a MacBook Pro with an Apple-supplied matte screen and love it. I have no idea how people can do serious work on a glossy screen: reflection, over saturated colors, ugly black edges (just a joke). One thing about the glossy screen: the screen resolution is a bit lower and so, easier to read. My screen's native resolution is higher and so, a bit tougher on my old eyeballs.

Comment: I agree, I can't stand glary, glossy screens. Heaven only knows how much damage I've done to my eyes by working on a laptop with a glossy screen; as soon as I switched to 27" matte ViewSonic displays, the frequency of headaches and the vision problems I was having dramatically decreased. By saying "normal," I mean "glossy," as when you order, it's an "upgrade" to get matte.

Comment: It just seems weird to me that they'd do the weird edge; my ViewSonic monitors have matte screens but glossy edges and they look _great_.

Comment: TK: "Weird" is in the eye of the beholder. Note that the most popular portable Mac on earth at the moment, the MacBook Air has your "weird" edge AND a semi-glossy screen: http://www.apple.com/macbookair/

Comment: FYI they don't offer matte displays anymore.  Last year was 2012 I think.

Answer (score 3):

I once saw someone using a sort of matte finish film on their MacBook display which seemed pretty effective.

It was something like the item in [**this review**](http://www.macworld.com/article/138610/2009/02/mbpantiglare.html)

Looks like you'd have to be very careful when applying it.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of options a simple Google search for Macbook screen protector brings up many sheets of anit-glare plastic that can be applied over the screen in the same way as an iPhone protector.

http://www.gearzap.com/power-support-anti-glare-screen-protector-macbook-pro-13-inch.html

Is one of the first page hits, it is UK based though.

Comment: Yes, a $10 matte electro-static overlay + a glossy MacBook Pro is ideal. I opted for a matte MBP, and not only is it less pretty, I wound up buying a screen overlay in the end anyways (to avoid getting dust all over the screen), which makes it about the same level of gloss as the alternative anyways!

Answer (score 2):

I have one of [these](http://www.powersupportusa.com/accessories/macbook-pro-15/anti-glare-film.html) on my glossy 15" MacBook Pro and love it. I use the same film on my iPhone 4S (and have used it previously on iPhone 4 and iPhone 3G with great success).

Comment: Thanks for the personal recommendation here, it's most appreciated. :)